# How do I store multiple values (with different types) in an array and print them out?

Tags: java, arrays, object, if-statement, java.util.scanner

My program asks the user to create a bank account. At the moment it can create only one account and print it out. I want to extend my program so that it can create muliple accounts by choosing the menu option again and again and finally print all the account details.

```
package bankapp_assignment;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class BankApp_Assignment {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BankAccount[] accounts = new BankAccount[10];

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int userChoose;
        String name = null;
        int accNum = 0;
        double initiateAmount = 0;
        double newAmm = 0;

        double depOrWith = 0;
        System.out.println("WELCOME TO OUR BANK!\n\n"
                + "...................\n"
                + "...................\n\n"
                + "Choose your optiin:\n"
                + "1. Create new account\n"
                + "2. View all the accounts property\n"
                + "3. Quit\n\n");

        System.out.println("*************\n"
                + "************");
        while (true) {
            userChoose = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            if (userChoose == 1) {
                /*the user must be able to create multiple accounts, let's say 10 accounts for instance
                 To open another new account the user should choose the menu option "1" again and continue...
                 */
                System.out.println("Enter your full name:");
                name = sc.nextLine();

                System.out.println("Choose an account number:");

                accNum = sc.nextInt();

                System.out.println("Enter an initiating amount:");

                initiateAmount = sc.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("\n-----------\n"
                        + "------------");
            } else if (userChoose == 2) {//view all the accounts property (including account number and initial balance)

            } else if (userChoose == 3) {
                System.exit(0);

            }
        }

    }

}
```

BankAccount:

```
package bankapp_assignment;

public class BankAccount {
    public void createAcc(){

    }
}
```

EDIT after Naman's answer:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BankAccount[] accounts = new BankAccount[10];

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int userChoose;
        String name = null;
        int accNum = 0;
        double initiateAmount = 0;
        double newAmm = 0;

        double depOrWith = 0;
        System.out.println("WELCOME TO OUR BANK!\n\n"
                + "...................\n"
                + "...................\n\n"
                + "Choose your optiin:\n"
                + "1. Create new account\n"
                + "2. View all the accounts property\n"
                + "3. Quit\n\n");

        System.out.println("*************\n"
                + "************");
        while (true) {
            userChoose = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            if (userChoose == 1) {
                /*the user must be able to create multiple accounts, let's say 10 accounts for instance
                 To open another new account the user should choose the menu option "1" again and continue...
                 */
                System.out.println("Enter your full name:");
                name = sc.nextLine();

                System.out.println("Choose an account number:");

                accNum = sc.nextInt();

                System.out.println("Enter an initiating amount:");

                initiateAmount = sc.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("\n-----------\n"
                        + "------------");

accounts[numOfAcc]=bankAcc;
                numOfAcc++;

            } else if (userChoose == 2) {//view all the accounts property (including account number and initial balance)

   for(BankAccount bankAccount: accounts){

                  System.out.println("Your name: " + name);
                 System.out.println("Your account number: " + accNum);
                 System.out.println("Your current balance: " + initiateAmount);
                 System.out.println("\n-----------\n"
                 + "------------");  

                  }



            } else if (userChoose == 3) {
                System.exit(0);

            }
        }

    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complete code with the **working answer**

```
package tester;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BankApp {

    static class BankAccount {
        private String name;
        private int accNum;
        private double initiateAmount;

        public BankAccount() {
            this.name = null;
            this.accNum = 0;
            this.initiateAmount = 0;
        }

        public void setAccNum(int accNum) {
            this.accNum = accNum;
        }

        public void setInitiateAmount(double initiateAmount) {
            this.initiateAmount = initiateAmount;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name + "\t" + accNum + "\t" + initiateAmount;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<BankAccount> bankAccounts = new ArrayList<BankAccount>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(true){
        System.out.println("WELCOME TO OUR BANK!\n\n"
                + "Choose your option:\n"
                + "1. Create new account\n"
                + "2. View all the accounts property\n"
                + "3. Quit\n");

            int option = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            switch(option){
                case 1:
                    BankAccount account = new BankAccount();
                    System.out.println("Enter your full name:");
                    account.setName(sc.nextLine());
                    System.out.println("Choose an account number:");
                    account.setAccNum(sc.nextInt());                    
                    System.out.println("Enter an initiating amount:");
                    account.setInitiateAmount(sc.nextDouble());
                    bankAccounts.add(account);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Name\tAcc No\tAmount");
                    for (BankAccount bankAccount : bankAccounts) {
                        System.out.println(bankAccount);
                    }
                    System.out.println("\n\n");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to have the `BankAccount` in seperate file do the following.

file `BankAccount.java`

```
public class BankAccount {
...
...
}
```

Comment: Faraj Farook, I liked the way u solved it but I never expected a class inside a class. How could it be doen without making a static class inside my main class?

Comment: Take the class and store it in a seprate file with the name `BankAccount.java`. Remove the `static` keyword and add `public` at that place

Comment: Faraj Farook, thanks it works now as i was expecting

Answer (score 2):

If you want to continue with array then you can do like initializing static variable first:

```
static int number = 0;
```

Change your block as below:

```
 if (userChoose == 1) {
    BankAccount ac = new BankAccount();
    //set account properties;
    accounts[number] = ac;
    number++;
 }
```

You can retrieve array like below:

```
for(BankAccount bankAccount: accounts){
   //bankAccount.getProperty();
}
```

Your code should be like

```
BankAccount bankAcc = null;
   if (userChoose == 1) {
       bankAcc = new BankAccount(); 
                /*the user must be able to create multiple accounts, let's say 10 accounts for instance
                 To open another new account the user should choose the menu option "1" again and continue...
                 */
                System.out.println("Enter your full name:");
                name = sc.nextLine();
                bankAcc.setName(name);//setter method of your bankAccount bean
                System.out.println("Choose an account number:");

                accNum = sc.nextInt();
                bankAcc.setAccountNum(accNum);
                System.out.println("Enter an initiating amount:");

                initiateAmount = sc.nextDouble();
                bankAcc.setInitialAmount(initialAmount);
                System.out.println("\n-----------\n"
                        + "------------");

accounts[numOfAcc]=bankAcc;
                numOfAcc++;

            }
```

Retrieve like as below:

```
else if (userChoose == 2) {//view all the accounts property (including account number and initial balance)

   for(BankAccount bankAccount: accounts){

                  System.out.println("Your name: " + bankAccount.getName());
                 System.out.println("Your account number: " + bankAccount.getAccountNum());
                 System.out.println("Your current balance: " + bankAccount.getInitialAmount());
                 System.out.println("\n-----------\n"
                 + "------------");  

                  }
```

Comment: hi Naman, I actually wanted to continue with the array I have created, thats what you did too. But what iff I want to print out the accounts property (by choosing the option 2). I think with static int number = 0; it can't print out all (or , may be i am wrong?). And also what if I want to print out a specific account details (by referring the account number from user), which I want to modify my program in future. With your given answer will it work fine?

Comment: I edited my answer. You can retrieve all the bankAccounts like that. If you want to get specific account then you can use equals method to get specific account.

Comment: Dear Naman, sorry for interrupting you again. I have edited my post , there I made change according to your suggestion. But it doesn't save the all the accounts properties in array. It stores only the last acount created, besides it prints everything 10 times. I think I have little misunderstanding somewhere, and hope it's not very hard for you to detect.

Comment: Are you able to run this code? As you have not set any property of bankacc

Answer (score 1):

1) Create an object class: for example

```
class BankAccount{
    private String userName;
    private String userSurname;
    private String birthDay;
    private int accountNumber;
    private int ibanNo;
    private int balance;
    public BankAccount(String userName, String userSurname, String birthDay, int accountNumber, int ibanNo, int balance) {
        super();
        this.userName = userName;
        this.userSurname = userSurname;
        this.birthDay = birthDay;
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
        this.ibanNo = ibanNo;
        this.balance = balance;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    public String getUserSurname() {
        return userSurname;
    }
    public void setUserSurname(String userSurname) {
        this.userSurname = userSurname;
    }
    public String getBirthDay() {
        return birthDay;
    }
    public void setBirthDay(String birthDay) {
        this.birthDay = birthDay;
    }
    public int getAccountNumber() {
        return accountNumber;
    }
    public void setAccountNumber(int accountNumber) {
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    }
    public int getIbanNo() {
        return ibanNo;
    }
    public void setIbanNo(int ibanNo) {
        this.ibanNo = ibanNo;
    }
    public int getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }
    public void setBalance(int balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

}
```

2) Create a global List with this object in your main class;

```
List<BankAccount> accounts = new ArrayList<BankAccount>();
```

3) Now you can add new accounts to your list;

```
accounts.add(new BankAccount(String userName, String userSurname, String birthDay, int accountNumber, int ibanNo, int balance));
```

4) Now you can add / get / remove accounts with using accounts list.

Comment: Mucahit, How do I print all the accounts?

Answer (score 1):

Create object of the bank account details and simply add to ArrayList
Use ArrayList data type from java.util package
Create a class with Bank account details in it simply import it to this class and write following code

```
List <BankAccount> accounts = new <BankAccount> ArrayList();
BankAccount object = new BankAccount();
//Set field here like

System.out.println("Enter your full name:");
                name = sc.nextLine();

                System.out.println("Choose an account number:");

                accNum = sc.nextInt();

                System.out.println("Enter an initiating amount:");

                initiateAmount = sc.nextDouble();
```

after that simple use

```
accounts.add(object);
```

it is perfect to store the generic data types or objects in such cases,
also use the switch cases over the if -then- else blocks its much readable and convinient

also use enhaced for loop to view accounts

```
for(BankAccount account:accounts){
System.out.println("ALL DETAILS FROM OBJECT");
}
```